# Angular 5 - Dev/QA build using ng build with uglify and minify (like ng build --prod)

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

I am using angular5 and angular-cli and have requirement to uglify/minify code which can be viewed in inspector tool of browser.
My angular-cli.json has:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

For production it is running fine by **ng build --prod**
But this can be used only for production enviornment.
I want to do same for dev enviornments but i am not able to acheive it.
I have already tried most of the options of build with value of prod except of --enviornment:

```
Flag                 --dev    --prod
--aot                false    true
--environment        dev      prod
--output-hashing     media    all
--sourcemaps         true     false
--extract-css        false    true
--named-chunks       true     false
--build-optimizer    false    true with AOT and Angular 5
```

For example

```
ng build --aot=true --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer true
```

But it is not working for me. Not creating uglified code for this enviornment(here dev).

how can I use same build command for other environments? How can i use prod optimisations in other environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your `dev` `environment.ts` values with the `--prod` optimizations, just specify so with the flag:

`ng build --prod --environment=dev`

This applies the `--prod` settings but overrides `--environment` for which environment file will be used.

In newer Angular CLI versions with the change to `angular.json`, replace `--environment` with `--configuration`. Since the default configuration uses `environment.ts`, just pass an empty string to it so the environment file doesn't get overwritten, e.g `--prod --configuration=`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by defining new environments on your `angular-cli.json` file, or `angular.json`

angular-cli.json:

```
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
  "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts"
}
```

angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": { ... },
  "qa": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Followed by creating the `environment.qa.ts` in the environments directory.

Read more about it over [here](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15)